# Lowering a symbol with import graphics

Tags: symbols, includegraphics

I have little graphic pictures that I'm using as symbols in mathematical equations. For example:

```
\def\detectorRed{\includegraphics[height=2.5ex]{DetectorRed}}
```

with a PNG of a detector ends up giving me a symbol for a red flashing light. If I use this in the equation:

```
$|\detectorRed\rangle$
```

I will see something in my text which looks like:

[image]

I'm adding a picture to show that the text itself between lines ends up being a bit too big to accommodate for the larger size of the new image-symbol. So, instead of simply shrinking the size until this effect goes away, what I want to do is shift the actual image down, which I think will fill up the whitespace in a way that looks better.

Any ideas how I can shift the image down?

Comment: You can try using `\raisebox{-0.2ex}{\includegraphics{…}}` (with a first argument to be adjusted to your real situation).

Comment: Another alternative would be to `\usepackage{adjustbox}` and then instead of `\includegraphics` you could use `\adjustimage{raise=-0.2ex, height=2.5ex}{<file-name>}`.